# Can't change stripe payment method origin and email

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I have integrated [Stripe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripe_(company)) in an iOS app, with a rubi back-end, payment method origin always showing United States (please see the attached screenshot). How I can change this to United Kingdom?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTxyG.png)

Also no emails are showing in the transaction dashboard (please see attached screenshot). What should be done so that every customer email will be shown there?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BmIG.png)

Comment: In Test Mode, the payment method will always be from the United States.

Comment: Re *"rubi back-end"*: Do you mean *"[Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) back-end"*